# Add another array after every 2 in an array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array

```
$array1 = Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [event_id] => 2
            [event_name] => Vectro
            [event_date_time] => 2016-06-20 15:25:39
            [location] => Edachira
            [gps_latitude] => 9.998671
            [gps_longitude] => 76.350319
            [event_thumb_img] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [event_id] => 3
            [event_name] => Illusions
            [event_date_time] => 2016-06-20 15:25:39
            [location] => Vazhakkala
            [gps_latitude] => 0.000000
            [gps_longitude] => 0.000000
            [event_thumb_img] => event_image/3/1464589975358.jpg
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [event_id] => 4
            [event_name] => Bass
            [event_date_time] => 2016-06-10 15:25:39
            [location] => Palarivattom
            [gps_latitude] => 10.003811
            [gps_longitude] => 76.346176
            [event_thumb_img] => 
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [event_id] => 5
            [event_name] => Bug
            [event_date_time] => 2016-06-16 15:25:39
            [location] => Irumpanam
            [gps_latitude] => 9.998671
            [gps_longitude] => 76.346176
            [event_thumb_img] => 
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [event_id] => 22
            [event_name] => Evolution unknown
            [event_date_time] => 2016-06-16 23:00:00
            [location] => Aluva
            [gps_latitude] => 0.000000
            [gps_longitude] => 0.000000
            [event_thumb_img] => event_image/22/IMG-20160405-WA0000.jpg
        )
)
```

And I have another array

```
$array2 = Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [adv_name] => Test3
            [adv_url] => 
            [adv_image] => adv/1/zmr.jpg
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [adv_name] => Test2
            [adv_url] => 
            [adv_image] => adv/1/zmr.jpg
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [adv_name] => Test1
            [adv_url] => 
            [adv_image] => adv/1/zmr.jpg
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [adv_name] => Test
            [adv_url] => 
            [adv_image] => adv/1/zmr.jpg
        )
)
```

I want this array as result from these two :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [event_id] => 2
            [event_name] => Vectro
            [event_date_time] => 2016-06-20 15:25:39
            [location] => Edachira
            [gps_latitude] => 9.998671
            [gps_longitude] => 76.350319
            [event_thumb_img] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [event_id] => 3
            [event_name] => Illusions
            [event_date_time] => 2016-06-20 15:25:39
            [location] => Vazhakkala
            [gps_latitude] => 0.000000
            [gps_longitude] => 0.000000
            [event_thumb_img] => event_image/3/1464589975358.jpg
        )

    [2] => Array
        (   
            [adv_name] => Test3
            [adv_url] => 
            [adv_image] => adv/1/zmr.jpg
        )  

    [3] => Array
        (
            [event_id] => 4
            [event_name] => Bass
            [event_date_time] => 2016-06-10 15:25:39
            [location] => Palarivattom
            [gps_latitude] => 10.003811
            [gps_longitude] => 76.346176
            [event_thumb_img] => 
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [event_id] => 5
            [event_name] => Bug
            [event_date_time] => 2016-06-16 15:25:39
            [location] => Irumpanam
            [gps_latitude] => 9.998671
            [gps_longitude] => 76.346176
            [event_thumb_img] => 
        )

    [5] => Array
        ( 
            [adv_name] => Test2
            [adv_url] => 
            [adv_image] => adv/1/zmr.jpg
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [event_id] => 22
            [event_name] => Evolution unknown
            [event_date_time] => 2016-06-16 23:00:00
            [location] => Aluva
            [gps_latitude] => 0.000000
            [gps_longitude] => 0.000000
            [event_thumb_img] => event_image/22/IMG-20160405-WA0000.jpg
        )
)
```

Please provide me with the proper code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do what you want, use this code:

```
<?php
$final_array = array();
for($k = 0, $j = 0; $j < count($array2); $k += 2, $j++) {

    for($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++) {
        if(isset($array1[$i + $k])
            $final_array[] = $array1[$i + $k];
    }

    if($j % 3 == 0)
        $final_array[] = $array2[$j];

}

print_r($final_array);
```

This code will go all `$array1`, if a key doesn't exist it will not add it. When on the time you go over `$array2` is multiple of 3 (is the 3rd, 6th, 9th time) it will add `$array2` to the final array you are looking for...

You **must** add more info... because I have the mood I am giving you this simple code, but please, the next time give more info about your problem. Stack Overflow is not a code service, we help, not make from 0 what you want.